# Is it possible to receive 1 byte of data all at once, instead of receiving each character individually with arduino bluetooth?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

I am creating a project using an arduino and my iphone as a bluetooth remote that gives data to my arduino. I need my program to be as fast as possible because the project I am making uses a very fast rotating sensored brushless DC motor and the more time it takes to get information from bluetooth to my arduino the less time my motor has to switch phases.

**Question:**

When I am sending data from my iphone to the arduino the only way I have been able to send data is by sending it 1 character at a time. For example - if I wanted to send the number "254" to my arduino, it would first send 2, then 5, then 4 at separate times, and then I would have to combine these 3 numbers together after receiving them to get the value "254".

Here is my code. Explanation of my code[can be found here](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/serial-input-basics-updated/382007) under example 2:

```
const byte numChars = 32;
char receivedChars[numChars];   // an array to store the received data
boolean newData = false;

void recvWithEndMarker() {
static byte ndx = 0;
char endMarker = '\n';
char rc;

while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
    rc = Serial.read();

    if (rc != endMarker) {
        receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
        ndx++;
        if (ndx >= numChars) {
            ndx = numChars - 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
        ndx = 0;
        newData = true;
    }
}
}

void showNewData() {
if (newData == true) {
    Serial.print("This just in ... ");
    Serial.println(receivedChars);
    newData = false;
}
```

}

Since the number "254" could be combined into 1 byte of data i'm wondering if it would be possible to send "254" to my arduino at the same time instead of sending all 3 characters separately then I would have to combine them later which takes up valuable time? Is it possible to receive a value of "254" directly from my iphone?

*Not sure if this helps, but I am using an HM - 10 as my bluetooth module.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But you can do it for the numbers up to 255. In your iOS,  assuming that you obtain this number as a `String`, you need to convert the number to an `UInt8` value. Then you set the characteristic's data with this value. If you want to send one byte at a time, you need to add some delay like 100ms so that iOS's BLE stack does not accumulate values to send it all within the same frame.

Answer (score 0):

To receive multibytes data you can use `Serial.readbytes` function. At first you should get the number of received data by using `Serial.available` function, Then use `Serial.readbytes` function to catch them all. 
So your `recvWithEndMarker` function would be like this:

```c
int recvWithEndMarker() {
  static int index = 0;

  char numRecBytes = Serial.available();
  if (index + numRecByes < numChars)) 
  {
    index = numChars - numRecByes;
  }
  if (numRecBytes > 0) 
  {
    if (Serial.readBytes(receivedChars, numRecBytes) == numRecBytes)
    {
      for (int chCounter = 0; chCounter < numRecBytes; chCounter++)
      {
        if (receivedChars[index + chCounter] == '\n')
        {
          receivedChars[index + chCounter] = '\0';
          index = 0;
          return 1;
        }
      }
    }
    index += numRecBytes;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This function returns 1 if the string ends with `'\n'`, otherwise returns 0.
**Note:**

1. this functions working in Non-blocking mode which means you may have to call it more than once to get all data.
2. This solution is for Text format data which means each digit has includes one byte, So the number 245 includes 3 bytes. This is better to use Binary format to combine 3 digits to one byte (For unsigned numbers less than 256).
3. This is just for receiver side on Arduino.